# Error 'A value of type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.' in Dart 2.2

Tags: string, dynamic, dart, aqueduct

since the last dart update (2.2)
I'm getting this error,

> 'A value of type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to a variable of type
>   'String'.'

which doesn't make much sense to me.
the code is absolutely trivial:

```
    class EmployeeMirror {
  EmployeeMirror(this.id, this.name);

  EmployeeMirror.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> _map) {
    id = _map['id'];      // error here
    name = _map['name'];  // and here
  }

  int id;
  String name;
}
```

I don't think is relevant, but this is in an Aqueduct project.

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You can disable this check by removing `implicit-cast: false` (or setting it to true) from the `analysis.options.yaml` file. https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks

Comment: I have the same issue, it's somehow related to Aqueduct

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class EmployeeMirror {
  EmployeeMirror(this.id, this.name);

  EmployeeMirror.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> _map) {
    id = _map['id'] as int;
    name = _map['name'] as String;
  }

  int id;
  String name;
}
```

Comment: I am also stuck in similar case. Can you help in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63779722/flutter-add-comma-separated-value-to-class-list

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
analyzer:
  errors:
    invalid_assignment: ignore
```