# A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future<String> _loadCurrencies() async {
  String uri = "http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?access_key=apikey";
  var response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse(uri), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
  var responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
  Map curMap = responseBody['rates'];
  currencies = curMap.keys.toList();
  setState(() {});
  print(currencies);
  return "Success";
}
```

It shows the error `A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>'.`

At first, I tried the `as Map` but I can't seem to solve this error.

Comment: Try this answer[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038667/error-a-value-of-type-dynamic-cant-be-assigned-to-a-variable-of-type-string#:~:text=1%20Answer,Votes) by @mezoni

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038667/error-a-value-of-type-dynamic-cant-be-assigned-to-a-variable-of-type-string#:~:text=1%20Answer,Votes) by @mezoni .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

When you do

```
Map curMap = responseBody['rates'];
currencies = curMap.keys.toList();
```

`curMap` is a `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` and `curMap.keys()` is a `Iterable<dynamic>`. Since `currencies` is a `List<String>`, you can't assign it to `curMap.keys().toList()`.

### The solution

Just change it to

```
Map<String, dynamic> curMap = responseBody['rates'];
currencies = curMap.keys.toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it will have strings, you can do

```
currencies = curMap.keys.toList().cast<String>();
```

Answer (score -1):

convert  keys to string

```
currencies = curMap.keys.map(e => e.toString()).toList();
```